# CSS challenge: background image transparency on active

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to replicate the following design on a web site, but so far my attempts have been somewhat fruitless. I know it's possible, but I believe my approach might be wrong.

The design:

[image]

[image]

My approach

```
<div class="nav-container">
   <nav class="nav">
       <ul class="nav-ul">
           <li><a href="#"><label>just another psd file</label></a></li>
           <li>
              <a href="#"><label>item 1</label></a>
              <ul>.... leave this out for now</ul>
           </li>
           <li><a href="#"><label>item 2</label></a></li>
           <li><a href="#"><label>item 3</label></a></li>
           <li><a href="#"><label>item 4</label></a></li>
           <li><a href="#"><label>item 5</label></a></li>
       </ul>
   </nav>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.nav-container {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
.nav-container nav {
    background-color: rgb(0, 189, 192);
    height: 95px;
    width: 100%;
}
.nav-container nav ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 62.5rem;
}
```

My problem here is that the transparency should occur on `<nav>` when an `<li>` has been hovered, but because it's a solid, full-width element, I cannot really 'cut' out a portion of it. I tried to do this with JavaScript and a transparent image, but the effect is not as I want it.

The approach should be as simple as stretching the `<ul>` full-width, centre the `<li>`'s to that and then on hover, set the `<li>`'s background state to transparent, but this approach seems rather daunting for such a 'simple' effect, no?

**UPDATE**

The problem is:

We have 'layers' in the example screen shot.

layer 1 is a black  with a 25% opacity

within layer 1 is another  representing layer 2 with a blue background color.

within layer 2 is a  bar which is centered

```
<div class="layer1">
   <div class="layer 2">
        <nav>
            <ul class="centered ul">
               <li>First part</li>
               <li>Item 1</li>
               <li>Item 2</li>
               <li>Item 3</li>
               <li>Item 4</li>
               <li>Item 5</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
   </div>
</div>
```

When the user lands on the page, 'First Part' should 'cut out' a part of the blue-background-layer (layer 2). When a user then hovers over Item 1, the 'First Part' should have a blue-background, and Item 1 should now be transparent.

Unfortunately I don't have a screenshot of this process :(.

My problem is, how do I 'cut out' the portion on Layer 2 (for the transparency to show Layer 1) when and any of the 5 items, is hovered and then activated (menu clicked)?

Comment: CSS doesn't have a parent selector. So you'll have to use JS.

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle demo of what you try ?

Comment: Why you can't just use `:hover` on `ul`?

Comment: i'll fiddle it now, the problem is how do you 'cut' out a portion of a solid layer? a background image won't work, and select the parent div based on the li:hover will change the transparency of the entire div, not the the portion that takes up the li-block...

Comment: Why can't you use grey instead of 25% black? What's the benefit in using transparent black? Using grey this thing is easy as pie.

Comment: because the menu sits ontop of an image, and the image should be visible through the hovered and active menu item. I'm not depicting this in the screen shots. quite a challenge

Comment: Without JS this is not possible, AFAIK. I could imagine having the nav in 25% black, and adding two blue bars (`<div>`) positioned `absolute` and with `z-index` lower than the nav-ul, one `left:0`, the other `right:0`. Then using JS to determine the hovered elements position and width, and setting the width of the bars. You'll gain an animated hover state if you set CSS transitions on width, which is also pretty neat.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/je59w24u/

Comment: @guest always someone who knows what they're doing. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you have a grey background, behind a blue background, an always visible grey line across the bottom and you want the background of an individual item to be grey on hover?

Personally I would eliminate layers 1 & 2 from your HTML and CSS.

```css
/*CSS for answer*/
body{
  background-image: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b5/Winnersh_Meadows_Trees.jpg);
  background-size: 100%;
  }
nav{
  display:block;
    height: 120px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
}
li:hover{
  background-color: transparent
}


/*basic styling to mimic OP design*/
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
ul{
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li{
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: 15%;
  height:100px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(0, 189, 192);
}
ul:before,
ul:after{
  float:left;
  display:block;
  content:"";
  width:12.5%;
  height:100%;
  background-color: rgb(0, 189, 192);
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
        <li>Item 5</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, i like this approach, like i stated in my question, i might be going about it the wrong way. note, that the 'grey' layer is required as it creates an effect on an image ontop of which this menu sits, as depicted in my updated screenshots

Comment: Hm. My reply got deleted. So here it is again. Given your additional information, I have updated my answer to solve your problem! Enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

Have the `<li>`s paint their own background, so that they can go transparent on `:hover`.

http://jsfiddle.net/je59w24u/

The idea is simple enough, but there's some more work to do so that we also cover the sides beyond the `<li>` elements. Here's a modified view to show the three parts that do this job: http://jsfiddle.net/je59w24u/1/

#### :before and :after

```
.nav-container nav ul:before {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 11.25rem;
    margin-right: 50%;
    content: "";
    background-color: rgb(128, 189, 192);
}

.nav-container nav ul:after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 11.25rem;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: 50%;
    content: "";
    background-color: rgb(0, 189, 212);
}
```

I've used absolute positioning and margins to wrangle these in place. For each, the side that doesn't go out to the edge finds its place by starting in the middle (via a 50% margin) and move out by half the width of the centered `<ul>` (11.25rem).

#### space after the floated `<li>`s

```
.fill {
    background-color: rgb(0, 209, 192);
    height: 95px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

It's just an additional `<li>`, but not floated. The `overflow: hidden` supposedly makes it not also paint behind the floats. I dunno, I saw it on this article, which probably explains it better than I can: http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/#making-room-for-floats

#### Then the `:hover` stuff

Now that the sides are painted, just remove the `background-color` from the `<nav>` and put them on the `<li>`s. And add a rule to make them have transparent background on `:hover`.

```
.punch:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

I added a class name so that `.punch` and `.fill` won't interfere with each other.